# PHP: Instantiate a class and get property

Tags: php

Is it possible it instantiate a new class and get a property without assigning it to a variable object.

example:

```
$fileid = 1;
$filepath = new fileclass($fileid)->path;
```

I know the above is incorrect but is the concept possible?

Comment: This is available as of PHP 5.4: *"Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar()."* - [see here](http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration54.new-features.php)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is in PHP >= 5.4.0

```
$filepath = (new fileclass($fileid))->path;
```

The brackets are important

Comment: [Actually this seems to be a PHP 5.4.0 feature](http://www.php.net//manual/en/migration54.new-features.php): "*Class member access on instantiation has been added, e.g. (new Foo)->bar().*"

Comment: @Ralph - sorry, my bad with the version, you do have it in 5.4.... but you need to get those brackets right